# ember application.hbs page {{outlet}} not render other page

Tags: ember.js, template-engine

Ember CLI version 2.7.0

In templates folder I created two files, application.hbs and post.hbs
application.hbs

```
<h2 id="title">balabala</h2>
{{outlet}}
```

post.hbs

```
<h3>I am from post.hbs</h3>
```

I expect "balabala I am from post.hbs" shows in browser, however I can only see "balabala".
Anybody could help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you created  route `post`?

Comment: `ember generate route post` this will create routes/post.js file and templates/post.hbs file and an entry to router.js file...thats all you are good to go to access `/post`

Comment: Include your router.js file in your question, please!

Comment: Which address did you enter to address bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've added the new route in your router.js file.

```
this.route('post');
```

Plus you will have to add a new post route.
Easiest is to user ember cli to generate the files for you in the future.

```
ember generate route post


Result :
installing
  create app/routes/post.js
  create app/templates/post.hbs
installing
  create tests/unit/routes/post-test.js
```